# TeamCity Send Email FxCop Notification

Tags: teamcity, fxcop

I currently have FxCop integrated as a build step on one of my TeamCity projects. It runs after the build and outputs errors.

[image]

It's working great. However what I really want is to have it email me an overview of the errors each time it runs so that I don't have to login to the TeamCity UI everytime. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is an email notification feature in your profile panel on the website, through which you can configure TeamCity to email you regarding builds either from specific build configurations, or specific projects, or all builds.

I am not certain whether there are enough features in this to cover emailing you the information you require, you will need to look into it yourself (It's the link with your name written on it in the top right for clarification). If there aren't enough options, a further custom build step would be required. This would need to download the FxCop log, process it into your desired human readable email, and send it off yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that TeamCity actually delivers the failed in the following email format by default!

```
> Build myBuild :: Build #15 successful (Inspections total: 5288 (-1),
> errors: 3350 (-1))  Agent: WIN-F6GHH45VG7K
```